# Calling mprotect to set the memory on the stack as read-only directly leads to a program SIGSEGV

Tags: c, linux, mprotect

I want to set the access attribute of an object on the stack to read-only, but as soon as I call mprotect, the process crashes. The approximate code is as follows:

```cpp
constexpr int kPageSize = 4096;
CHECK_EQ(kPageSize, sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));
volatile char padding1[kPageSize] = {0};
NetDataHead head;
volatile char padding2[kPageSize] = {0};

// ...
auto align_down_4k_ptr = steel::AlignDownPointer(&head, kPageSize);
CHECK_EQ(reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(align_down_4k_ptr) % kPageSize, 0);
if (auto rc = mprotect(align_down_4k_ptr, kPageSize, PROT_READ); rc != 0) {  // A
  LOG_F("Failed to mprotect ptr: %p, rc: %d", align_down_4k_ptr, rc);
}

// Read-only codes ...

if (auto rc = mprotect(align_down_4k_ptr, kPageSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE); rc != 0) {
  LOG_F("Failed to mprotect ptr: %p, rc: %d", align_down_4k_ptr, rc);
}
```

The program crashes directly at point A, which is the location of the first mprotect call.

By referring to the manual, it appears that this should not cause a crash in Linux. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

[man 2 mprotect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IXGA.png)

I would like to protect the "head" structure on the stack using mprotect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page says it is permissible, and indeed it appears the kernel makes the stack region read only. Yet the granularity of the memory protection hardware is coarse, typically 4K, 8K or more so other areas of the stack got protected too, such as space used to save registers, which causes a crash as soon as the system call returns.

Your attempt at isolating the data by defining 2 padding arrays does not work. Contiguous definitions do not guarantee contiguous instantiation. The padding arrays might not get instantiated at all if you do not use them. Making them `volatile` is irrelevant.

You should either define a larger structure or use a mmapped memory block for this.

Comment: This is a form of UB. Taking the address of a stack variable and then aligning it downward. We don't know what else is in the stack frame at that point at that location. The two padding arrays are unused and may be elided by the compiler. We could be making a variable R/O that is unrelated to `head`. Doing this on the stack isn't something I'd recommend. But, if one must: `struct align { char padding1[4096]; NetData head; char padding2[4096]; };` Then, on the stack: `struct align head_wrapper;` and use `&head_wrapper.head;`

Comment: chqrlie, @Craig Estey My issue has been resolved，thank you very much! However, I would like to understand the root cause. Earlier, chqrlie mentioned "such as space used to save registers, which causes a crash as soon as the system call returns", but I want to know why it crashes immediately upon returning from the system call. Isn't popping the stack and restoring registers from kernel mode to user mode a read-only operation? Additionally, when entering kernel mode to save registers, shouldn't it use the newly allocated memory region after stack growth, which is not protected?

Comment: @magicsun For your original code, disassemble it. Run under `gdb` and single step individual instructions. I think you'll be surprised at what you find.

Comment: @magicsun  Also, because `padding1` and `padding2` are VLAs (not supported in c++?), they _both_ must be grown _below_ `head` on the stack dynamically, so you are _guaranteed_ to write protect 99% of the stack frame for the function. You think/hope your frame looks like: `pad1|head|pad2|ret` but it is: `pad1|pad2|other_stuff|head|stuff|ret`

Comment: @Craig Estey Thanks! I checked with gdb and indeed, as you said, pad1 and pad2 are arranged together, and mprotect has protected unexpected memory. After the call to mprotect returns, there is an instruction that saves the register values to the memory protected by mprotect.